# Addview image not displaying in table cell

Tags: ios, addsubview

I modified a subview table cell using addsubview to include an additional image on the right (besides the one on the left).  I had it working great until I added a search bar at the top.  Somehow in doing that, the right image stopped displaying.  I tried removing the search bar but have been unable to get the image to display.  I have a feeling I made a typo inadvertently or somehow messed up the code.

Here is the method.  It works except that the image on the right no longer displays.  Would appreciate it if anyone can spot my error or suggest what is going wrong.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *protoCell = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:protoCell];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:protoCell];
    }
   //     IDModel * item;
    IDModel * item = nil;

//  if no search
    //item  = [self.tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //following for search

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        item = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        item = [self.tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = item.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.sub;

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:item.pic];
    //following crops and rounds image
    //add image to right
    UIImageView *rightimage;
    rightimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0,0.0,80.0,45.0)];
    rightimage.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
//    rightimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.jpg"];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:rightimage];
       rightimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:item.pic];

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One concern here is that you shouldn't add views to a UITableViewCell from the view controller. Table view cells are reused, so each time this cell gets reused you'll be adding a new view to it without first removing the old one.

Instead, create a UITableViewCell subclass, and add rightimage (which I would rename rightImageView to be consistent with Apple's naming conventions) in the -initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. Then set the rightView's frame in the -layoutSubviews method, or set up the auto layout constraints in the -initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: right after creating the rightImageView.

Make rightImageView a public property (put it in the .h file) so you can assign the image from the view controller.

Comment: would you ditch the subview in storyboard and do the whole cell as a custom cell?

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer a complete custom cell.